# Why doesn't my draggable svelte work properly after scaling it?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I have created a svelte component to allow for draggable Dom elements:

```html
<script>
    export let posX = 0
    export let posY = 0

    let moving = false
    let offsetX
    let offsetY

    function dragStart(e) {
        const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect()

        offsetX = e.pageX - rect.left
        offsetY = e.pageY - rect.top

        moving = true
    }

    function dragStop() {
        moving = false
    }

    function dragMove(e) {
        if (moving) {
            posX = e.pageX - offsetX
            posY = e.pageY - offsetY
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .draggable {
        user-select: none;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: grab;
    }

    .draggable:active {
        cursor: grabbing;
    }
</style>

<svelte:window on:mouseup={dragStop} on:mousemove={dragMove} />

<div
    on:mousedown={dragStart}
    style="top: {posY}px; left: {posX}px;"
    class="draggable"
>
    <slot/>
</div>
```

When I add the CSS property `transform: scale(0.5);` to a div containing draggable components the draggable components stop working as expected. Their positions get offset from the mouse position.

```html
<script>
    import Draggable from "./Draggable.svelte"
</script>

<style>
    .box {
        background: red;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    
    .container {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <Draggable>
        <div class="box"/>
    </Draggable>
    
    <Draggable posY={250}>
        <div class="box"/>
    </Draggable>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the svelte REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/679692b94afc48b48a2a3ebd39875ea0?version=3.42.5

How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Why would you want to scale down the container?  I could understand scaling down the individual draggable elements for effect but why the container?

Comment: I'm building a node-based editor, similar to [this](https://reactflow.dev/examples/). I need to implement a pan and zoom feature. It seems unnecessary to scale down each individual element inside the container if you can just scale the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scale down the container, two things happen:

1. The container size becomes smaller than the viewport, causing an offset in the mouse position that isn't corrected.
2. The units for the `top`/`left` CSS properties are now half as big, which also isn't corrected for.

To fix this, we have to calculate the offset of the parent container relative to the viewport and pass that value into your `<Draggable>` component. We also need to pass in the scale value that we are using.

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import {onMount} from "svelte"
    import Draggable from "./Draggable.svelte"
    
    let parent;
    let parentOffset = {x: 0, y:0}
    
    onMount(() => {
        let rect = parent.getBoundingClientRect()
        parentOffset = {x: rect.x, y: rect.y}
    })
</script>

<style>
    .box {
        background: red;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    
    .container {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
</style>

<div class="container" bind:this={parent}>
    <Draggable {parentOffset} scale={0.5}>
        <div class="box"/>
    </Draggable>
    
    <Draggable posY={250} {parentOffset} scale={0.5}>
        <div class="box"/>
    </Draggable>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Draggable.svelte -->
<script>
    export let posX = 0
    export let posY = 0
        
        export let parentOffset;
      export let scale;

    let moving = false
    let offsetX
    let offsetY

    function dragStart(e) {
        const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect()

        offsetX = e.pageX - rect.left
        offsetY = e.pageY - rect.top

        moving = true
    }

    function dragStop() {
        moving = false
    }

    function dragMove(e) {
        if (moving) {
            // new math! we subtract the parent offset to correct the parent shift
            // and also divide by the scale to correct the scale multiplication
            posX = ((e.pageX - offsetX)-parentOffset.x)/scale
            posY = ((e.pageY - offsetY)-parentOffset.y)/scale
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .draggable {
        user-select: none;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: grab;
    }

    .draggable:active {
        cursor: grabbing;
    }
</style>

<svelte:window on:mouseup={dragStop} on:mousemove={dragMove} />

<div
    on:mousedown={dragStart}
    style="top: {posY}px; left: {posX}px;"
    class="draggable"
>
    <slot/>
</div>
```

New REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/9ec1a1598e8f407e8ec807dbb8a4d92b?version=3.42.5